# Reading Gradle build parameters

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle project with subprojects that I can issue separate build commands if I don't want to build all the subprojects at once. For example,

```
parent
  subprojectA
  subprojectB
  subprojectC
```

I can then issue commands like `./gradlew :subprojectA:assemble :subprojectC:assemble`. What I like to do is construct a meaning git tag from each subproject `group` and `version` values for those subprojects that are being built, i.e., `group` and `version` for only `subprojectA` and `subprojectC` in this case. I am thinking of writing a standalone plugin to do this but unsure where / how to get this information at build time. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `group` and `version` (as well as any other project property) is available globally in your build script.

```
task myTask << {
    println group + "-" + version
}
```

If you are writing a binary plugin you can also access properties off the `Project` object itself via the `property()` method.

```
def group = project.property('group')
```

**Edit**

If you want to determine if a particular project is being built you can inspect the `TaskExecutionGraph`.

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(':subprojectA:assemble')) {
        println 'Will build subprojectA'
    }
}
```

Comment: Got that, thanks but how do I get specifically only the subprojects that are being built?

Comment: If you only want something to happen when a particular subproject is built then just add a task to each subproject. Just make sure it's part of the task graph by doing something like `assemble.dependsOn myTask`.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the suggestion but that's introducing an artificial dependency determined at run time and i would like to avoid it, isn't there another way to know which subproject and tasks are being built at run time?

Comment: Yes, in that case you can use `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { }`. Check out the [javadoc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I need, if you have any example code, that'll be great! If you add this to your answer, I'll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: I've added a code example to my answer. I hope that helps you out.